# Fetch images URL from XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using the below code to fetch the  $movie->id from the response XML

```
<?php   
$movie_name='Dabangg 2';
        $url ='http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/accd3ddbbae37c0315fb5c8e19b815a5/%22Dabangg%202%22';

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $movies = $xml->movies->movie;
   foreach ($movies as $movie){
        $arrMovie_id = $movie->id;
    }
```

?>

the response xml structure is

[image]

How to fetch image URL with thumb size?

Comment: Where is the `$movie_name` variable is defined?

Comment: @NullVoid Added now. The file I posted is not full code thats y I missed

Comment: Also give proper URL so that we can get proper xml

Comment: @NullVoid Proper XML is edited

Comment: Where did you put this php code?i wan't to develop such an app myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below an easy way to get only specific images.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$images = $xml->xpath("//image");
//echo "<pre>";print_r($images);die;
foreach ($images as $image){
    if($image['size'] == "thumb"){      
        echo "URL:".$image['url']."<br/>";
        echo "SIZE:".$image['size']."<br/>";
        echo "<hr/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. It echoed all the sizes. What if I only want the thumb size. I want to save the URL in database. Also will loop for every movie I will pass . since I have posted hardcoded movie . But in real code the movie variable is an array

Comment: I edited code with condition. To save in DB you need to fire insert query.

Comment: Unless you're using namespaces (which you're not) you generally don't need the ->attributes() method. You can just use array-style access, e.g. `if($image['size'] == 'thumb')`

Comment: Every time will you load xml file with URL with movie name? Then No problem you just have to replace your URL with movie name you want.

Comment: @NullVoid OK Thanks let me test it with insert query .

Comment: @NullVoid Thanks for helping me .It worked. Since there were two thumb images So I added 'if($image['size'] == "thumb" && $image['type']=="poster")' to get poster thumb images. Now works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attributes() method of SimpleXmlElement.

Example:

```
$imageAttributes = $movie->images[0]->attributes();
$size = $imageAttributes['size'];
```

See the documentation at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: Do I have to use it in loop ?

Comment: I think you would want to do that yes. But I don't know what it is exactly what you are trying to accomplish. I would guess you would want to use it in your `foreach ($movies as $movie){ ... }` loop somewhere. The example only gets the attributes for the first image. If you want something with all the images, you would need a `foreach ( $movie->images as $image ) { ... }` loop inside your movies loop. And do `$attributes = $image->attributes(); $size = $attributes['size'];` to get the sizes for each image..

Comment: Ofcourse `$attributes['url'];` also exists. As it contains all the attributes of the element on which you called the attributes() method.

Comment: Unless you're using namespaces (which you're not) you generally don't need the `->attributes()` method. You can just use array-style access, e.g. `$movie->images[0]['size']`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: select only `URL` attributes with `size = "thumb"` and `type = "poster"`:

```
$urls = $xml->xpath("//image[@size='thumb' and @type='poster']/@url");
```

if you expect only 1 url, do:

```
$url = (string)$xml->xpath("//image[@size='thumb' and @type='poster']/@url")[0];
echo $url;
```

working live demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wdmEay

Comment: What is I need only type poster and size thumb

Comment: @Deonia: then why don't you write that in your question? See edit.